# Is there another way to calculate time performing a function without clock()?

Tags: c

```
void play(){
    ...
    int f;
    ...
        if(per==4){
            f=clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            int min,sec;
            min = f/60;
            sec = f%60;
            printf("You have won the game in %d turns and %d:%02d!!!",turn,min,sec);
            break;
        }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why? Do you need something that `clock` is not giving you?

Comment: What's wrong with 'clock`?

Comment: If you want actual elapsed time and not processor time, you can use `time()`. [C Date and time utilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c)

Comment: I linked to the C++ page. Here's the C page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono

Answer (score 0):

Standard timing methods including `clock()` are provided in time.h.  One function that might be used is `time()`:

```
time_t start = time(NULL) ;

// Something that takes time here...

// Elapsed time in minutes+seconds.
int f = time(NULL) - start ;
int min = f / 60 ;
int sec = f % 60 ;
```

Non-standard means may be provided by your platform such as Windows performance counters.

Strictly the return value from `time()` need not be in seconds and the `difftime()` function should be used rather than `time(NULL) - start`, but you are unlikely to encounter a system where `time_t` is not in seconds, and `difftime()` returns a `double` which may not be desirable in some cases:

```
int f = (int)difftime( time(NULL), start ) ;
int min = f / 60 ;
int sec = f % 60 ;
```

Comment: thank you, actually that day I found the time(NULL) after I post this question, but still thanks for your help, you answer my question in just 30 minutes, overstack is really convenient